# How to use Bundler with path specified Ruby version

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am on a VM (Lucid 64b) with a system Ruby version of 1.9.3p0.

I have a Ruby script that creates a .deb file -- The script needs to use Ruby 1.8.7 which I have installed in `/foo/ruby/1.8.7`.
There is an existing `Gemfile` to be used with Bundler
I can't use RVM and I can't install gems at the system level.

My `.bashrc` includes (and has been sourced)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/foo/ruby/1.8.7/bin
```

but `ruby -v` still gives me

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
```

### Questions

- How can I change the Ruby version for my user to use Ruby 1.8.7?

  I've run: `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

  So in that directory (actually `./vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/cache/gems`) are all the gems I need but, when I run the Ruby script it doesn't find the required gems. I run the script like so `/foo/ruby/1.8.7 script_to_gen_deb_file.rb`
- How can I get ruby to see/use the bundled gems?

### Update

I was able to solve it. I needed to use

```
/foo/ruby1.8.7/bundle exec /foo/ruby1.8.7/ruby script_to_gen_deb_file.rb
```

I had tried this before, but I got an unrelated error and believed there was an environment problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change your path so the special ruby gets precedence?

```
export PATH=/foo/ruby/1.8.7/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank You for the response. Typing that in changes the ruby version for that session(but not when put in the .bashrc), but it still doesn't load the gems.